# SCSS: Increase a property by fixed pixels

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to increase the font-size of some font awesome icons on hover.Because the font size is different for all the icons, I was wondering would it be possible to add some pixels to existing font-size on hover through SCSS.

Example:-

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" >Designs
            <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" >Mobile Applications 
            <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" >Ecommerce 
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu li:hover{
  i{
    //increase font size by 20px
  }
 }
```

In the above code all the icons have different font-size.How to increase font-size by 20px on hover through SCSS.

Comment: @cimmanon, thanks for the link.As said in your answer, it is possible through variables. How can that be done.I am new to scss. Please guide me.

Comment: I disagree that this question is a duplicate of the other one. (I'm the second re-open vote.) I don't think that every Sass question which can by answered "use a variable" is a duplicate. Because the example code leads to some fairly different solutions, the questions are different.

Comment: @KatieK No, there isn't an "option" here.  If the non-hover state of the element is 10px, there isn't a way to set it to 30px on hover without either using variables or hard coding it.  If the OP simply wanted to make the font size 20px larger than the parent element's font-size, there isn't even a guaranteed way to do that with CSS because neither em nor percentage units can be converted to px (you can only get an approximation *if* the user has not modified their default font-size).

Comment: @cimmanon - One can use `calc` in font-size; that's CSS of course. http://codepen.io/KatieK2/pen/wBgGyp It's really up to the OP and community to decide whether answers are useful, even if they bend the rules of the question.

Comment: @KatieK That's not the question being asked, though.  The OP specifies "the font size is different for all the icons" and that they want to "increase font-size by 20px on hover" for all of their icons.

Comment: @cimmanon - The pen I wrote **demonstrates** increasing the current font-size by 20px.

Comment: @KatieK Exactly, it demonstrates increasing the `i` element's font-size by 20px over the **parent's** (li) font-size.  It does not demonstrate increasing the `i` element's hover font-size over the original font-size of the `i` element, which is what is being asked here.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is marked as duplicate. OP can achieve the desired output by @cimmanon's answer. Here is a slight modification to the fiddle to better suit the OP's need: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNgKgr

Comment: @aBhijit Try reading the comments.  As I already stated, that is **NOT** what is being asked for.  The OP has something like `i.foo { font-size: 15px }` and `i.bar { font-size: 18px }` and wants to make all of them 10px larger on hover.  You can't do that with calc.  You have to spell each one out individually.

Comment: I understand that the feature is not available in SCSS for now but after going through comments I think it can be solved by wrapping the required element in a dummy element having properties which required element should have had and then using calc function.